# How do I choose what pipe diameter for basement drains?

Tags: bathroom, basement

I’m converting a basement utility room into a bathroom as part of an overall conversion of the basement into an apartment. Needless to say oh my drain locations need to change or be added.

What is the best standard resource to consult for figuring out which diameter ABS to use on each drain line? I’ve read general guidelines online but it’s unclear what the authority is. Local code is nearly illegible.

I also welcome any feedback on what I’ve mocked up here. Thanks so much for your time!

[image]

Comment: your floor drain needs a trap. (unless that's actually a closet flange), you tub connection looks to be  too close to the toilet stack. venting possibly also an issue.  if you poke around on the internet you should bw able to find a free copy of "international plumbing code"   don't let the name fool you, like "world series"  it's basically an an American thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I’ll try to find that book. 

FYI that floor drain is a little misleading. The toilet stack runs up an exterior foundation wall and the floor drain is for the bottom of the exterior concrete stairs. They’re covered with an awning so not much rain gets down there. Helpful to have just in case. Is it standard to do traps on an exterior drain? Best to do it to avoid smells? 

Not sure how to fix the distance of the toilet and the tub. Will think on that!

Comment: in many places outdoor ground drains are required to flow to a different sewer (storm sewer)  without a trap it will behave as a vent, and vent outlets typically have to be above the roof.

Comment: The required diameters relate to the wet venting you propose and the lengths. Update your diagram with the lengths as well.